# jquery lightbox save image

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, lightbox2

I am using lightbox from http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/.
it did works but the images cannot be saved..when right click it only allow to save the html link... how to enable user to save the displayed image?

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Lightbox</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css">
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="gallery">
            <div class="galleryItem">   <a href="img/features.PNG" data-lightbox="image" data-title="My caption" rel="lightbox">
                        <img src="img/features.PNG" />
                    </a>

            </div>
            <div class="galleryItem">   <a href="img/2.jpg" data-lightbox="image" data-title="My caption" rel="lightbox">
                        <img src="img/2.jpg" />
                    </a>

            </div>
            <div class="galleryItem">   <a href="img/1.jpg" data-lightbox="image" data-title="My caption" rel="lightbox">
                        <img src="img/1.jpg" />
                    </a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

**js**

```
/**
 * Lightbox v2.7.1
 * by Lokesh Dhakar - http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/
 *
 * @license http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/
 * - Free for use in both personal and commercial projects
 * - Attribution requires leaving author name, author link, and the license info intact
 */

(function() {
  // Use local alias
  var $ = jQuery;

  var LightboxOptions = (function() {
    function LightboxOptions() {
      this.fadeDuration                = 500;
      this.fitImagesInViewport         = true;
      this.resizeDuration              = 700;
      this.positionFromTop             = 50;
      this.showImageNumberLabel        = true;
      this.alwaysShowNavOnTouchDevices = false;
      this.wrapAround                  = false;
    }

    // Change to localize to non-english language
    LightboxOptions.prototype.albumLabel = function(curImageNum, albumSize) {
      return "Image " + curImageNum + " of " + albumSize;
    };

    return LightboxOptions;
  })();


  var Lightbox = (function() {
    function Lightbox(options) {
      this.options           = options;
      this.album             = [];
      this.currentImageIndex = void 0;
      this.init();
    }

    Lightbox.prototype.init = function() {
      this.enable();
      this.build();
    };

    // Loop through anchors and areamaps looking for either data-lightbox attributes or rel attributes
    // that contain 'lightbox'. When these are clicked, start lightbox.
    Lightbox.prototype.enable = function() {
      var self = this;
      $('body').on('click', 'a[rel^=lightbox], area[rel^=lightbox], a[data-lightbox], area[data-lightbox]', function(event) {
        self.start($(event.currentTarget));
        return false;
      });
    };

    // Build html for the lightbox and the overlay.
    // Attach event handlers to the new DOM elements. click click click
    Lightbox.prototype.build = function() {
      var self = this;
      $("<div id='lightboxOverlay' class='lightboxOverlay'></div><div id='lightbox' class='lightbox'><div class='lb-outerContainer'><div class='lb-container'><img class='lb-image' src='' /><div class='lb-nav'><a class='lb-prev' href='' ></a><a class='lb-next' href='' ></a></div><div class='lb-loader'><a class='lb-cancel'></a></div></div></div><div class='lb-dataContainer'><div class='lb-data'><div class='lb-details'><span class='lb-caption'></span><span class='lb-number'></span></div><div class='lb-closeContainer'><a class='lb-close'></a></div></div></div></div>").appendTo($('body'));

      // Cache jQuery objects
      this.$lightbox       = $('#lightbox');
      this.$overlay        = $('#lightboxOverlay');
      this.$outerContainer = this.$lightbox.find('.lb-outerContainer');
      this.$container      = this.$lightbox.find('.lb-container');

      // Store css values for future lookup
      this.containerTopPadding = parseInt(this.$container.css('padding-top'), 10);
      this.containerRightPadding = parseInt(this.$container.css('padding-right'), 10);
      this.containerBottomPadding = parseInt(this.$container.css('padding-bottom'), 10);
      this.containerLeftPadding = parseInt(this.$container.css('padding-left'), 10);

      // Attach event handlers to the newly minted DOM elements
      this.$overlay.hide().on('click', function() {
        self.end();
        return false;
      });

      this.$lightbox.hide().on('click', function(event) {
        if ($(event.target).attr('id') === 'lightbox') {
          self.end();
        }
        return false;
      });

      this.$outerContainer.on('click', function(event) {
        if ($(event.target).attr('id') === 'lightbox') {
          self.end();
        }
        return false;
      });

      this.$lightbox.find('.lb-prev').on('click', function() {
        if (self.currentImageIndex === 0) {
          self.changeImage(self.album.length - 1);
        } else {
          self.changeImage(self.currentImageIndex - 1);
        }
        return false;
      });

      this.$lightbox.find('.lb-next').on('click', function() {
        if (self.currentImageIndex === self.album.length - 1) {
          self.changeImage(0);
        } else {
          self.changeImage(self.currentImageIndex + 1);
        }
        return false;
      });

      this.$lightbox.find('.lb-loader, .lb-close').on('click', function() {
        self.end();
        return false;
      });
    };

    // Show overlay and lightbox. If the image is part of a set, add siblings to album array.
    Lightbox.prototype.start = function($link) {
      var self    = this;
      var $window = $(window);

      $window.on('resize', $.proxy(this.sizeOverlay, this));

      $('select, object, embed').css({
        visibility: "hidden"
      });

      this.sizeOverlay();

      this.album = [];
      var imageNumber = 0;

      function addToAlbum($link) {
        self.album.push({
          link: $link.attr('href'),
          title: $link.attr('data-title') || $link.attr('title')
        });
      }

      // Support both data-lightbox attribute and rel attribute implementations
      var dataLightboxValue = $link.attr('data-lightbox');
      var $links;

      if (dataLightboxValue) {
        $links = $($link.prop("tagName") + '[data-lightbox="' + dataLightboxValue + '"]');
        for (var i = 0; i < $links.length; i = ++i) {
          addToAlbum($($links[i]));
          if ($links[i] === $link[0]) {
            imageNumber = i;
          }
        }
      } else {
        if ($link.attr('rel') === 'lightbox') {
          // If image is not part of a set
          addToAlbum($link);
        } else {
          // If image is part of a set
          $links = $($link.prop("tagName") + '[rel="' + $link.attr('rel') + '"]');
          for (var j = 0; j < $links.length; j = ++j) {
            addToAlbum($($links[j]));
            if ($links[j] === $link[0]) {
              imageNumber = j;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      // Position Lightbox
      var top  = $window.scrollTop() + this.options.positionFromTop;
      var left = $window.scrollLeft();
      this.$lightbox.css({
        top: top + 'px',
        left: left + 'px'
      }).fadeIn(this.options.fadeDuration);

      this.changeImage(imageNumber);
    };

    // Hide most UI elements in preparation for the animated resizing of the lightbox.
    Lightbox.prototype.changeImage = function(imageNumber) {
      var self = this;

      this.disableKeyboardNav();
      var $image = this.$lightbox.find('.lb-image');

      this.$overlay.fadeIn(this.options.fadeDuration);

      $('.lb-loader').fadeIn('slow');
      this.$lightbox.find('.lb-image, .lb-nav, .lb-prev, .lb-next, .lb-dataContainer, .lb-numbers, .lb-caption').hide();

      this.$outerContainer.addClass('animating');

      // When image to show is preloaded, we send the width and height to sizeContainer()
      var preloader = new Image();
      preloader.onload = function() {
        var $preloader, imageHeight, imageWidth, maxImageHeight, maxImageWidth, windowHeight, windowWidth;
        $image.attr('src', self.album[imageNumber].link);

        $preloader = $(preloader);

        $image.width(preloader.width);
        $image.height(preloader.height);

        if (self.options.fitImagesInViewport) {
          // Fit image inside the viewport.
          // Take into account the border around the image and an additional 10px gutter on each side.

          windowWidth    = $(window).width();
          windowHeight   = $(window).height();
          maxImageWidth  = windowWidth - self.containerLeftPadding - self.containerRightPadding - 20;
          maxImageHeight = windowHeight - self.containerTopPadding - self.containerBottomPadding - 120;

          // Is there a fitting issue?
          if ((preloader.width > maxImageWidth) || (preloader.height > maxImageHeight)) {
            if ((preloader.width / maxImageWidth) > (preloader.height / maxImageHeight)) {
              imageWidth  = maxImageWidth;
              imageHeight = parseInt(preloader.height / (preloader.width / imageWidth), 10);
              $image.width(imageWidth);
              $image.height(imageHeight);
            } else {
              imageHeight = maxImageHeight;
              imageWidth = parseInt(preloader.width / (preloader.height / imageHeight), 10);
              $image.width(imageWidth);
              $image.height(imageHeight);
            }
          }
        }
        self.sizeContainer($image.width(), $image.height());
      };

      preloader.src          = this.album[imageNumber].link;
      this.currentImageIndex = imageNumber;
    };

    // Stretch overlay to fit the viewport
    Lightbox.prototype.sizeOverlay = function() {
      this.$overlay
        .width($(window).width())
        .height($(document).height());
    };

    // Animate the size of the lightbox to fit the image we are showing
    Lightbox.prototype.sizeContainer = function(imageWidth, imageHeight) {
      var self = this;

      var oldWidth  = this.$outerContainer.outerWidth();
      var oldHeight = this.$outerContainer.outerHeight();
      var newWidth  = imageWidth + this.containerLeftPadding + this.containerRightPadding;
      var newHeight = imageHeight + this.containerTopPadding + this.containerBottomPadding;

      function postResize() {
        self.$lightbox.find('.lb-dataContainer').width(newWidth);
        self.$lightbox.find('.lb-prevLink').height(newHeight);
        self.$lightbox.find('.lb-nextLink').height(newHeight);
        self.showImage();
      }

      if (oldWidth !== newWidth || oldHeight !== newHeight) {
        this.$outerContainer.animate({
          width: newWidth,
          height: newHeight
        }, this.options.resizeDuration, 'swing', function() {
          postResize();
        });
      } else {
        postResize();
      }
    };

    // Display the image and it's details and begin preload neighboring images.
    Lightbox.prototype.showImage = function() {
      this.$lightbox.find('.lb-loader').hide();
      this.$lightbox.find('.lb-image').fadeIn('slow');

      this.updateNav();
      this.updateDetails();
      this.preloadNeighboringImages();
      this.enableKeyboardNav();
    };

    // Display previous and next navigation if appropriate.
    Lightbox.prototype.updateNav = function() {
      // Check to see if the browser supports touch events. If so, we take the conservative approach
      // and assume that mouse hover events are not supported and always show prev/next navigation
      // arrows in image sets.
      var alwaysShowNav = false;
      try {
        document.createEvent("TouchEvent");
        alwaysShowNav = (this.options.alwaysShowNavOnTouchDevices)? true: false;
      } catch (e) {}

      this.$lightbox.find('.lb-nav').show();

      if (this.album.length > 1) {
        if (this.options.wrapAround) {
          if (alwaysShowNav) {
            this.$lightbox.find('.lb-prev, .lb-next').css('opacity', '1');
          }
          this.$lightbox.find('.lb-prev, .lb-next').show();
        } else {
          if (this.currentImageIndex > 0) {
            this.$lightbox.find('.lb-prev').show();
            if (alwaysShowNav) {
              this.$lightbox.find('.lb-prev').css('opacity', '1');
            }
          }
          if (this.currentImageIndex < this.album.length - 1) {
            this.$lightbox.find('.lb-next').show();
            if (alwaysShowNav) {
              this.$lightbox.find('.lb-next').css('opacity', '1');
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };

    // Display caption, image number, and closing button.
    Lightbox.prototype.updateDetails = function() {
      var self = this;

      // Enable anchor clicks in the injected caption html.
      // Thanks Nate Wright for the fix. @https://github.com/NateWr
      if (typeof this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title !== 'undefined' && this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title !== "") {
        this.$lightbox.find('.lb-caption')
          .html(this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title)
          .fadeIn('fast')
          .find('a').on('click', function(event){
            location.href = $(this).attr('href');
          });
      }

      if (this.album.length > 1 && this.options.showImageNumberLabel) {
        this.$lightbox.find('.lb-number').text(this.options.albumLabel(this.currentImageIndex + 1, this.album.length)).fadeIn('fast');
      } else {
        this.$lightbox.find('.lb-number').hide();
      }

      this.$outerContainer.removeClass('animating');

      this.$lightbox.find('.lb-dataContainer').fadeIn(this.options.resizeDuration, function() {
        return self.sizeOverlay();
      });
    };

    // Preload previous and next images in set.
    Lightbox.prototype.preloadNeighboringImages = function() {
      if (this.album.length > this.currentImageIndex + 1) {
        var preloadNext = new Image();
        preloadNext.src = this.album[this.currentImageIndex + 1].link;
      }
      if (this.currentImageIndex > 0) {
        var preloadPrev = new Image();
        preloadPrev.src = this.album[this.currentImageIndex - 1].link;
      }
    };

    Lightbox.prototype.enableKeyboardNav = function() {
      $(document).on('keyup.keyboard', $.proxy(this.keyboardAction, this));
    };

    Lightbox.prototype.disableKeyboardNav = function() {
      $(document).off('.keyboard');
    };

    Lightbox.prototype.keyboardAction = function(event) {
      var KEYCODE_ESC        = 27;
      var KEYCODE_LEFTARROW  = 37;
      var KEYCODE_RIGHTARROW = 39;

      var keycode = event.keyCode;
      var key     = String.fromCharCode(keycode).toLowerCase();
      if (keycode === KEYCODE_ESC || key.match(/x|o|c/)) {
        this.end();
      } else if (key === 'p' || keycode === KEYCODE_LEFTARROW) {
        if (this.currentImageIndex !== 0) {
          this.changeImage(this.currentImageIndex - 1);
        } else if (this.options.wrapAround && this.album.length > 1) {
          this.changeImage(this.album.length - 1);
        }
      } else if (key === 'n' || keycode === KEYCODE_RIGHTARROW) {
        if (this.currentImageIndex !== this.album.length - 1) {
          this.changeImage(this.currentImageIndex + 1);
        } else if (this.options.wrapAround && this.album.length > 1) {
          this.changeImage(0);
        }
      }
    };

    // Closing time. :-(
    Lightbox.prototype.end = function() {
      this.disableKeyboardNav();
      $(window).off("resize", this.sizeOverlay);
      this.$lightbox.fadeOut(this.options.fadeDuration);
      this.$overlay.fadeOut(this.options.fadeDuration);
      $('select, object, embed').css({
        visibility: "visible"
      });
    };

    return Lightbox;

  })();

  $(function() {
    var options  = new LightboxOptions();
    var lightbox = new Lightbox(options);
  });

}).call(this);
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 2):

Enable save image from lightbox plugin:

You can set the light box navigator parent div to position relative by overriding that class not going straight to edit the plugin css, not recommend to do that.

```
.lb-container .lb-nav {
    position: relative;
}
```

It's sad that the plugin doesn't provide more option than what it provided, user expected more option than that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save image directly using browser then you will lost next/previous image functionality.
For that you need to remove/comment one line from light box style sheet like below:

```css
.lb-nav {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Lightbox v2.8.1 but if you modify the lightbox.css adding the following code to the bottom it will allow you to right click and select "Save picture as ...".

The area that can right clicked is the area not defined by .lb-prev and .lb-next.  the width % parameter may have to be adjusted.  The default width was 34% and 64% leaving a narrow band on the left side that could be right clicked.  A good value I found was 34%.

```
    .lb-nav {
       pointer-events: none;
    }

    .lb-prev, .lb-next {
       pointer-events: auto;
    }
```